# Grouping by date difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and can't seem to figure out how to populate the "episode" column with a sequence of numbers where there is an increment of 1 only where the dates("start_date","end_date") difference is greater than 30 days.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  But, you've already done the `lag()`, so:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when date_delta > 30 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by start_date) + 1 as episode
from t;
```

If you need to calculate `date_delta` as well:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when start_date > dateadd(day, 30, prev_date)
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (partition by id order by start_date) + 1 as episode
from (select t.*,
             lag(start_date) over (partition by id order by start_date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t;
```